# JavaScript - Different function-runtime processing the same data-structure - How is that possible?

Tags: javascript

My task is to write a test-function. So that the runtime of two different function-implementation (doing the same task) can be compared. Task is to change a dash-separated string to camel case notation. But that's secondary here.

I guess I should show the whole test-setup first:

```js
// The array with the test-data. I have shorten it a lot.
// The original-array, used for the test, is much larger.
var test = ["Alpha-North-blue-teal-West-pink-crimson-Delta", 
  "crimson-Gamma-blue-Delta", 
  "white-cyan-South-blue-East-East-South-blue", 
  "teal-black-East-East", 
  "South-black", 
  "black-cyan", 
  "West-white-Beta-Gamma-red-North-Alpha-Beta", 
  "Gamma-North-West-lime-North-crimson-North", 
  "blue-red-orange", 
  "red-West-South"];
 
// -- Implementation 1 ----------
function dashedToCamelCase( dashed ) {
  var ret;
  var parts;

  if (typeof dashed !== 'string' || !dashed) {
    return '';
  }   

  parts = dashed.split('-');
  ret = parts[0].toLowerCase();     
  parts = parts.slice(1);

  ret = parts.reduce(function(previous, current) {
    return previous +
      current.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
      current.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  }, ret);

  return ret;
}
 
// -- Implementation 2 ----------
function dashedToCamelCase2( dashed ) {
  if( typeof dashed != "string" || dashed.length==0 )
    return "";
  return dashed.toLowerCase().replace(/\-([a-z]?)/g, function(match, letter) {
    return letter.toUpperCase();
  });
}
  
function getRuntime(testData, func, countRunningTests) {
  var i;
  var tmp = 0;
  var sum = 0;
  var min = 0;
  var max = 0;
  var ret = {};

  var getRuntimeSingleTest = function() {
    var start = Date.now(); 

    testData.forEach( function( item ) {
      func(item);
    });

    return (Date.now() - start);
  }

  for (i = 1; i <= countRunningTests; i++) {

    tmp  = getRuntimeSingleTest( testData, func );

    sum += tmp;

    if (min === 0 || tmp < min) {
      min = tmp;
    } else if (tmp > max) {
      max = tmp;
    }
  }

  ret.averageRuntime = sum / countRunningTests;
  ret.minimalRuntime = min;
  ret.maximalRuntime = max;

  return ret;
}
 
function displayResults( results, funcName ) {
  funcName = funcName || '';

  console.log('\n%s', funcName);

  for ( var i in results ) {
    console.log('%s : %s ms', i, results[i]);
  }
}

displayResults(getRuntime(test, dashedToCamelCase, 100), ' - Implementation using reduce() - ');
displayResults(getRuntime(test, dashedToCamelCase2, 100), ' - Implementation using replace() - ');
```

What I don't understand:
I let the functions process the whole string-array many times. **The results for the minimum and the maximum runtime differ a lot.** With a lot I mean the maximal-runtime is six or seven times higher then the minimal-runtime.

The average-runtime also differs a lot. But not multiple times.

[image: Test-run 1]

[image: Test-run 2]

**How is that possible?**

It's always the same data which are used. The results should be at least similar.

Test have been runned on a computer with Windows 7 and Internet Explorer 11.

CPU: Intel i5-3230M 2.60 GHz

RAM: 8 GB

**UPDATE**

Like in the accepted answer suggested I increased in count of test-runs.

What I can say now is that the more test-runs used the more stable becomes the average-runtime.

So it's likely as supposed: The variations in the minimum- and maximum-results are an result of other processes which demand CPU-time.

Comment: Is this the only process running on your computer?

Comment: @ArgOn No. There are also the usual stuff like Outlook, Skype, Security Software plus a lot of others in the background. I guess ... for remote- access, -software-installation. I guess the system-admins have a lot such stuff running on these machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run time depends on running processes on your computer. So if your antivirus starts to do some stuff, than your browser process must wait.

Better run these tests like 100000 times same function to calculate average.

Comment: Thanks for all hints so far. I will increase the count of test-runs and then update the question.

Comment: @st88 Always remember that on such small intervals there always will be some inconsistency. In the end it's only electricity that floats through your hardware. Lots of random stuff will happen.